# Which preposition should I use here "my interest and appreciation xx..."

Tags: prepositions

> My interest and appreciation xx foreign languages.

When writing a sentence with two nouns that use two different prepositions, how should I form the sentence?

Should I use the latter's; interest and appreciation of...

Should I use both; my interest in and appreciation of...

Or are both usable, or something else more correct?

Comment: A duplicate of this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252204/what-preposition-should-i-use-after-a-conjunction-with-two-nouns?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: The correct phrase is "my interest in and appreciation of...". The incorrect phrase is "my interest and appreciation of..."

"When prepositional phrases are used in a parallel series, prepositions (with, to, of, over, under, by, etc.) should be repeated with every element of the series unless all elements use the same preposition. A common error is to repeat prepositions unnecessarily, resulting in a stilted style." (Grammarly"

In the following sentence, correct parallel structure is not used. The prepositions are different but not all are repeated.
Example: The man drove the car through buildings, alleyways and over people.

In the following sentence, correct parallel structure *is* used. The prepositions are repeated because they are not the same.
Example: The man drove the car through buildings, through alleyways and over people.

However, If you want to replace people with "tunnels", it would be appropriate to say: "The man drove the car through buildings, alleyways and tunnels.

According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/interest_1), the only preposition that can follow "interest" is "in". So, "my interest in" is correct but "my interest for" is incorrect.

Note: I highly suggest you read the full article [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallel-structure-prepositions/)